# How can I find which version of CoreOS is running on a given machine

Tags: coreos

I can ssh to a box running CoreOS, but can't seem to find a way to check what version of CoreOS is running there. Could not find anything in the documentation either.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The version is stored in

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Comment: This seems to work for Ubuntu as well (probably then for Debian as well).